# Separating Text that has spaces into separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, split

I have a Textcol that looks like this:

example of Text:

```
Note:test note
Phone Call: Fairview Wines & Spirits
Number Called: 1 604  601-8000
Phone Description: Main
Subject: Arrange meeting
Result: Arranged interview
Duration: 00:00:09
```

I want to get the subject, Result and note into four separate columns if possible.. I have tried two approached:

First example:

```
SELECT "Note"=SUBSTRING(TextCol,1,25),"Subject"=SUBSTRING(TextCol,110,25)
 ,"Result"=SUBSTRING(TextCol,135,33) FROM AMGR_Notes where type = 2
```

Second example:

```
 SELECT
    RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(T.TextCol, A.SubjectStart + 8, A.ResultStart - A.SubjectStart - 8), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''))) AS [Subject]
    ,RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(T.TextCol, A.ResultStart + 7, A.DurationStart - A.ResultStart - 7), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''))) AS Result
    ,RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(T.TextCol, 6, A.PhoneStart - 6), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''))) AS Note
FROM AMGR_Notes T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES
        (
            CHARINDEX('Phone Call:', T.TextCol)
            ,CHARINDEX('Subject:', T.TextCol)
            ,CHARINDEX('Result:', T.TextCol)
            ,CHARINDEX('Duration:', T.TextCol)

        )
    ) A (PhoneStart, SubjectStart, ResultStart, DurationStart);
```

The second example gives an error:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to
>   the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I am not a super genuis when it comes to SQL, so i dont understand the error.
I am also wondering if a CASE statement might work better in this instance

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please tag correct database you are using, I assume its T-sql

Comment: can you provide the expected output.

Comment: It's simple, isn't it? Run a `select` that shows you all the strings, their `len()s`, and the indices you are trying to use into `substring()`. Now look at them all very closely. The result might be surprising!

Comment: Querying would be a lot easier if you converted the data to a usable form. Instead of raw text you could convert the data into XML or JSON. SQL Server supports XML since 2005, JSON since 2016. Or you could add calculated columns that return the individual fields based on the formulas you already use. You can convert the existing data to JSON by replacing eg `:` with `" : "`, newlines with `",` and wrapping the result in `{   }`

Comment: Expected output would be: for columns:

Note          |   Result                   |    Subject             | Duration
test note    | Arranged Interview | Arrange Meeting | 00:00:09

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with a case statement as below:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN A.ResultStart - A.SubjectStart >= 8
    THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(T.TextCol, A.SubjectStart + 8, A.ResultStart - A.SubjectStart - 8), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')))
    ELSE ''
END
AS [Subject],
CASE
    WHEN A.DurationStart - A.ResultStart >= 7
    THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(T.TextCol, A.ResultStart + 7, A.DurationStart - A.ResultStart - 7), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')))
    ELSE ''
END
AS Result,
CASE
    WHEN A.DurationStart - A.ResultStart >= 7
    THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(T.TextCol, A.DurationStart + 9, A.DurationStart - A.ResultStart - 9), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')))
    ELSE ''
END
AS Duration,
CASE
    WHEN A.PhoneStart >= 6
    THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(T.TextCol, 6, A.PhoneStart
- 6), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')))
    ELSE ''
END
AS Note
FROM AMGR_Notes T
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    (
    CHARINDEX('Phone Call:', T.TextCol)
    ,CHARINDEX('Subject:', T.TextCol)
    ,CHARINDEX('Result:', T.TextCol)
    ,CHARINDEX('Duration:', T.TextCol)
    )
) A (PhoneStart, SubjectStart, ResultStart, DurationStart)


where t.type = '2'
```

Comment: Great that you found your own solution. But be aware, that this will break, if the input is not always in the expected order (or additional elements get in between). My answer's got a downvote, don't know why, but it is much more tolerant...

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done super clean and efficiently just using CROSS APPLY. Here's some on-the-fly inline function logic to handle a single string (forgive my naming - I'm in a hurry):

```
DECLARE @string varchar(8000) = 
'Phone Call: Fairview Wines & Spirits
Number Called: 1 604  601-8000
Phone Description: Main
Subject: Arrange meeting
Result: Arranged interview
Duration: 00:00:09';

SELECT  
  [Phone Call] = MAX(CASE s.n WHEN 1 THEN here.yougo END),
  [Subject]    = MAX(CASE s.n WHEN 2 THEN here.yougo END),
  [Result]     = MAX(CASE s.n WHEN 3 THEN here.yougo END),
  [Duration]   = MAX(CASE s.n WHEN 4 THEN here.yougo END)
FROM (VALUES (@string)) t(s) -- target.string
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1,'Phone Call:'),(2,'Subject:'),(3,'Result:'),(4,'Duration:')) s(n,t) -- search.text
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(s.t, t.s), LEN(s.t))) st(l,ln)                              -- start.location, start.length
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(char(10), t.s, st.l+st.ln+1),0),8000))) e(ln) -- end line
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(t.s, st.l+st.ln, e.ln-(st.l+st.ln)))) here(yougo);
```

This returns:

```
Phone Call                 Subject          Result              Duration 
-------------------------- ---------------- ------------------- ---------
Fairview Wines & Spirits   Arrange meeting  Arranged interview  00:00:09
```

The execution plan is fantastic - a total subtree cost of 0.0000071 (on my PC). To apply this logic to a table you would do this:

```
DECLARE @AMGR_Notes TABLE (someid int identity primary key, somestring varchar(8000));
INSERT @AMGR_Notes VALUES 
('Phone Call: ACME Treats
Number Called: 1 604 555-9988
Phone Description: Old School Landline
Subject: Buy Ice Cream
Result: He sold me some
Duration: 00:00:01'),
('Phone Call: Fairview Wines & Spirits
Number Called: 1 604  601-8000
Phone Description: Main
Subject: Arrange meeting
Result: Arranged interview
Duration: 00:00:09');

SELECT 
  t.someid,
  [Phone Call] = MAX(CASE s.n WHEN 1 THEN here.yougo END),
  [Subject]    = MAX(CASE s.n WHEN 2 THEN here.yougo END),
  [Result]     = MAX(CASE s.n WHEN 3 THEN here.yougo END),
  [Duration]   = MAX(CASE s.n WHEN 4 THEN here.yougo END)
FROM @AMGR_Notes tt
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (tt.someid,tt.somestring)) t(someid,s) -- target.string
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1,'Phone Call:'),(2,'Subject:'),(3,'Result:'),(4,'Duration:')) s(n,t) -- search.text
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(s.t, t.s), LEN(s.t))) st(l,ln)                              -- start.location, start.length
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(char(10), t.s, st.l+st.ln+1),0),8000))) e(ln) -- end line
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(t.s, st.l+st.ln, e.ln-(st.l+st.ln)))) here(yougo)
GROUP BY t.someid;
```

The MAX-CASE logic is another way to pivot but is cleaner and easier IMO (Credit to Jeff Moden for teaching me the technique.) The key for performance here (also true for using pivot) would be to make sure there is an index on the column which you are grouping by which, in my example, is the someid column.

Comment: That's a very nice and clever approach!

Comment: Btw: This first `CROSS APPLY` is just to use `t.s` and `t.someid` instead of `tt.somestring` and `tt.someid`? I'm pretty sure this is not needed...

Comment: Tested it against my own approach and yours is much faster (about x4)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, TextCol VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Phone Call: Fairview Wines & Spirits
    Number Called: 1 604  601-8000
    Phone Description: Main
    Subject: Arrange meeting
    Result: Arranged interview
    Duration: 00:00:09
');

WITH RowWise AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(TextCol,CHAR(13),'') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),CHAR(10),'</x><x>')  + '</x>' AS XML) AS OneRow
    FROM @tbl 
)
,EachRow AS
(
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(r.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS RowText
    FROM RowWise
    CROSS APPLY OneRow.nodes('/x[text()]') AS A(r)
)
SELECT LEFT(RowText,CHARINDEX(':',RowText)-1)
      ,SUBSTRING(RowText,CHARINDEX(':',RowText)+1,1000)
FROM EachRow;
```

The result

```
Phone Call           Fairview Wines & Spirits
Number Called        1 604  601-8000
Phone Description    Main
Subject              Arrange meeting
Result               Arranged interview
Duration             00:00:09
```

### UPDATE

Added `PIVOT` to get this in one line

```
WITH PlainLineBreak AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,REPLACE(TextCol,CHAR(13),CHAR(10)) AS TextCol
    FROM @tbl
)
,LineWise AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT TextCol AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),CHAR(10),'</x><x>')  + '</x>' AS XML) AS OneLine
    FROM PlainLineBreak 
)
,EachLine AS
(
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(r.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS LineText
    FROM LineWise
    CROSS APPLY OneLine.nodes('/x[text()]') AS A(r)
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT LEFT(LineText,CHARINDEX(':',LineText)-1) AS ColumnName
          ,SUBSTRING(LineText,CHARINDEX(':',LineText)+1,1000) AS ColumnValue
    FROM EachLine
) AS t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ColumnValue) FOR ColumnName IN([Note],[Phone Call],[Number Called],[Phone Description],[Subject],[Result],[Duration])
) As p
```

the result

```
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+
| Note      | Phone Call               | Number Called   | Phone Description | Subject         | Result             | Duration |
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+
| test note | Fairview Wines & Spirits | 1 604  601-8000 | Main              | Arrange meeting | Arranged interview | 00:00:09 |
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi downvoter, mind to explain? A downvote without a reason is - uhm - cowardish...

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way may be:

```
FROM AMGR_Notes T CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Phone Call:', T.TextCol), 0)
              NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Subject:', T.TextCol), 0),
              NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Result:', T.TextCol), 0),
              NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Duration:', T.TextCol), 0)
             )
     ) A(PhoneStart, SubjectStart, ResultStart, DurationStart);
```

Comment: Thank you - i tried this and i get the error:
Msg 1011, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The correlation name 'T' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.

Comment: @JR83 . . . This is *your* `FROM` clause.  I didn't change anything other than the contents of `A`.

Comment: This only returns the position of each word and doesn't really get the OP any closer to a solution.

Comment: @AlanBurstein . . . No, this returns `NULL` instead of an invalid character position, so the query will not return any errors.

Comment: My bad. I mistakenly thought this was intended to be a complete solution. Sorry Gordon (I just read your Data Mining Techniques - 3rd Edition, very good stuff)